# Energy corrections to be added in my DFT input of Quantum ESPRESSO for studying catalytic activity of MoS2 for hydrogen evolution reaction

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, computational-chemistry, condensed-matter, materials-engineering

While investigating 'catalytic activity of MoS2 (monolayer) in hydrogen  evolution reaction', what are the energy corrections that I am supposed to add in the DFT input (using Quantum ESPRESSO) to get meaningful results?

Comment: Please fix the grammar.